# React-native text layout

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, react-native-paper

I have a following react-native component:

```
const TaskItem = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <View
        style={{
          marginTop: 32,
          marginHorizontal: 8,
          display: 'flex',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
        }}
      >
        <Text style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>
          <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>Title:</Text>
        </Text>
        <Text>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              color: '#000000',
              backgroundColor: 'blue',
            }}
            numberOfLines={2}
          >
            Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text Very long text
          </Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

It produces the following screen (background-colors for debugging):

[image: Screen]

What I want is:

1. blue text not to overflow the red container on the right (respect the `marginHorizontal: 8`)
2. blue text to start at the beginning of red container on the left (wrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution. Check [this](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/taskitem-example) out from implementation

Your `TaskItem` should look like this

```
const TaskItem = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        marginTop: 32,
        marginHorizontal: 8,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
      }}>
      <Text style={{ marginRight: 8 }}>Title:</Text>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: '#000000',
          }}
          numberOfLines={2}>
          Very long text Very long text VeVery long text Very long text Very
          long text Very long text VeryVery long text Very long text Very long
          text Very long text VeryVery long text Very long text Very long text
          Very long text VeryVery long text Very long text Very long text Very
          long text Veryry long text Very long text Very long text
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```